# gcloud SDK: difference between command line interface and tools?

Tags: gcloud

After installing Google Cloud SDK, when I ran `gcloud components list`, I could see a component name called "BigQuery Command Line Tool" and "Cloud DNS Admin Command Line Interface"

Is there a distinction in the nature of command line tools vs interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things labeled as "Command Line Tool" typically refer to standalone tools like the bq tool or the gsutil tool.  Things labeled as "Command Line Interface" are functionality that get exposed through the unified gcloud tool.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the same functionality is available from gcloud SDK and the GUI interfaces, as they are frontends to the same APIs. Sometimes there are differences, though. There are operations which can only be performed or are only available in one of them, because the APIs are not exposed the same way in both.

The main difference is that the GUI tools are designed only for human usage, while the command line tools can be used programmatically too, due to the way they expose the APIs to the clients.